# Can GoogleCloudVision API for PDF OCR output to PubSub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am using the following code to request an OCR operation on the Google cloud vision API:

```
    from google.cloud import vision
    from google.cloud import storage
    from google.protobuf import json_format
    # Supported mime_types are: 'application/pdf' and 'image/tiff'
    mime_type = 'application/pdf'

    # How many pages should be grouped into each json output file.
    batch_size = 2

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    feature = vision.types.Feature(
        type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

    gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=gcs_source_uri)
    input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(
        gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)

    gcs_destination = vision.types.GcsDestination(uri=gcs_destination_uri)
    output_config = vision.types.OutputConfig(
        gcs_destination=gcs_destination, batch_size=batch_size)

    async_request = vision.types.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature], input_config=input_config,
        output_config=output_config)

    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(
        requests=[async_request])
```

When I call the `AsyncAnnotateFileRequest` operation I am passing a `GcsDestination` `OutputConfig` object. With this object I am telling the API to write the result to a GoogleCloudStorage bucket. I wonder if it is possible to write to PubSub instead? I looked around the documentation but it looks like it is not possible, as last resort thought to ask here. Maybe I am missing something?

**EDIT:**
I am exploring synchronous requests, where I can request the OCR, receive the text as response and then write to PubSub. Like this:

```
request = vision.types.AnnotateFileReques(features=[feature], input_config=input_config)

response = vision_client.batch_annotate_files(requests=[request])
```

but I am getting 
`AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision_v1.types' has no attribute 'AnnotateFileReques'` but from the [doc](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.AnnotateFileRequest) it should be there.
Suggestions?

Comment: Simple typo - you miss a **t**

Comment: ah damn, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

I kid you not there is a detailed tutorial on how to do this with Python. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr [image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have seen the tutorial before. However that's text extraction from images. What I need is extraction from PDF documents. The tutorial uses `.text_detection` and as you can read from the docs (https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/vision/gapic/v1/api.html) it is used for images only. That method is blocking and returns the extracted text, which is later written in the pub sub.

Answer (score 0):

The async annotate method writes final results to GCS. You can set up a GCS trigger to process the results when written to your GCS bucket.

See storage triggers: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage